# Passing-by-reference value of a method to another class

Tags: c++, xcode, pass-by-reference

I am trying to do a operation with the value of method's result in other class, I passed by reference the `wingArea` value, and I tried also with the method `span()` in the `clsSpanCalculation`, but Xcode displays: "Member function 'span' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const clsSpanCalculation', but funtion is not marked const"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

class clsSpanCalculation{
    float wingArea, aspectRatio;
public:
    clsSpanCalculation(){}
    float get_wingArea(void)const{return wingArea;}
    void set_wingArea(float Sw){wingArea = Sw;}
    float get_aspectRatio(void)const{return aspectRatio;}
    void set_aspectRatio(float AR){aspectRatio = AR;}

    float span(){
        float span;
        span = sqrt(aspectRatio*wingArea);
        return span;
    }
};

class clsChordParameters{
    float percentRectArea, percertTrapArea, taperRatio;
public:
    float get_percentRectArea(void)const{return percentRectArea;}
    void set_percentRectArea(float Srect){percentRectArea = Srect;}
    float get_percentTrapArea(void)const{return percertTrapArea;}
    void set_percentTrapArea(float Strap){percertTrapArea = Strap;}
    float get_taperRatio(void)const{return taperRatio;}
    void set_taperRatio(float lambda){taperRatio = lambda;}

    float rootChord (const clsSpanCalculation &sC){
        float rootChord, lambdaplus;
        lambdaplus= taperRatio + 1;
        rootChord = (2*(sC.get_wingArea()*(percentRectArea*(lambdaplus)+(2*percertTrapArea))))/((sC.span()*lambdaplus)/2);
        return rootChord;
    }

    float tipChord (const clsSpanCalculation &sC){
        float rootChord, tipChord, lambdaplus;
        lambdaplus= taperRatio + 1;
        rootChord = (2*(sC.get_wingArea()*(percentRectArea*(lambdaplus)+(2*percertTrapArea))))/((sC.span()*lambdaplus)/2);
        tipChord = rootChord*taperRatio;
        return tipChord;
    }
};
```

Here is the line of the code where Xcode displays the message:

```
rootChord = (2*(sC.get_wingArea()*(percentRectArea*(lambdaplus)+(2*percertTrapArea))))/((sC.span()*lambdaplus)/2);
```

I will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mark `span()` as `const` like you already have with `get_wingArea()` and `get_aspectRatio()`:

```
float span() const {
    float span;
    span = sqrt(aspectRatio*wingArea);
    return span;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `span` method as `const` (in other words, state that it will not modify the instance that you give it).

You need to do this because `rootChord` and `tipChord` take a parameter that is `const clsSpanCalculation &` (in other words, a reference to a constant clsSpanCalculation instance).

```
float span() const {
   ...
}
```